# hiding a flash swf to the left

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a swf object that is to the left of a header div that is 1000px wide. the swf is 303px wide. How would I make the swf on the left hide behind the window when the windows is only, say, 1050px wide?

Kinda like how this one is: http://eu.blizzard.com/diablo3/index.xml

notice how the object get hidden, still plays, but doesn't lose it's aspect ratio?
How does someone do this?

the code is set up like this:

```
<div class="swf">
  object
</div>
<div class="header">
  nav stuff
</div>
```

I've tried to make the header 1303 wide, but then on resize it just stops and keeps moving everything that is under it, and the swf stays put

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make the css property  position on class swf to absolute and and `z-index` to -1 it will hide behind the header and then you can let the header be `1000px`